# CSS: positioning of an element using jquery in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, css-position

I have an html `div` element which I want to be positioned statically, but I don't know in advance where exactly to put it. So when I want to fix it in its current position, I use this great trick:

```
var pos = $('#id_of_div').offset();
$('#id_of_div').css('position','fixed').css(pos);
```

It works perfectly on all the browsers I tried, except for IE. Suggestions?

Comment: What version of IE are you using (ps check for compattability mode)

Comment: `position: fixed` is recognized from IE7+ (With a DOCTYPE that triggers Standards mode).
Do you really need to support IE6 ?

Comment: Be sure to use proper version of jQuery that supports IE. You might need to add something like:
`<!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/lib/jquery/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all. Apparently, the problem was a missing `DOCTYPE` declaration, as suggested by @laruiss.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the css3 pie-plugin http://css3pie.com/documentation/pie-js/ or add the selectivizr plugin http://selectivizr.com/ to make older IE versions accept CSS3 attributes, which might solve your problem, but PLEASE, do at least stop using IE-versions below 9/10, it will save you for a lot of trouble...

Comment: Almost universally when a designer uses an older version of IE, it's at the client's request...